# Unable to convert java List to javascript ArrayList

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying convert one List of String of Java to an ArrayList of javascript.The code is as follows-

```
var viewByFilterData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(('<%=(List<String>)session.getAttribute("filters")%>')));
```

When I am printing the viewByFilterData variable I am getting following output-

> '[Cameras, Clothing, Computer Hardware, Footwear, Mobile Phones,
>   Watches]'

But when I tried to print the above variable using a simple for loop I got characters one by one('[' then 'C' then 'a' ...) instead of getting one item at a time(like 'Camera' then 'Clothing'...)

Any ideas on how can I convert this to a Javascript array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple string, which you can convert to Array by splitting it:

```
'[Cameras, Clothing, Computer Hardware, Footwear, Mobile Phones,Watches]'
.split(/\[|\]|,/) //to make array
.map(function(c){return c.trim();}) //to get rid of spaces
.filter(function(c){return c.length > 0}) // to get rid of empty elements and '[' and ']'
```